# PHP http error not allowed access

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Failed to load https://test.com/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://test.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

on top of your API file.

Comment: Should never use *

Comment: @LawrenceCherone If you are working on universal API then, it is okay to use it but you have to add further security checks to ensure safety.

Comment: No, you should still avoid it, instead if you want to allow all you should use the `origin` header value which is sent in the preflight request, adding a single header is not the right way to do it. [See this image](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/9ea48e5f02e4aaea34dc7f7584ee1bb0680e098e/687474703a2f2f7777772e68746d6c35726f636b732e636f6d2f7374617469632f696d616765732f636f72735f7365727665725f666c6f7763686172742e706e67)

Comment: [Most do it wrong so easy mistake.](https://github.com/search?q=Access-Control-Allow-Origin%3A+%2A&type=Code)